# MagicToolbox_MagicZoomPlus_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

**MagicToolbox_MagicZoomPlus_Helper_Data' not found**
while load  my magento homepage it show this error
i don't know wt to do?
 pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recently installed an extension?

Try the following.

1. Disable Compilation (if enabled)

   Go to `System > Tools > Compilation` and hit the `Disable` button
2. Clear your Magento cache.

   Go to `System > Cache Management`, Select all of the cache types and select refresh.  Also click the `Flush Magento Cache` and `Flush Cache Storage` buttons.
3. Disable the MagicToolbox Extension

   Go to `System > Configuration > Advanced` and disable all Modules Output with the `MagixToolbox_` namespace.  After doing this, refresh your Magento cache (see step 2).
4. If all of the above doesn't work, delete the extensions module XML from the `app/etc/modules/` directory.

   In your Magento root folder, go to `app/etc/modules` and delete the files beginning in `MagicToolbox_...xml`.  After deleting the file, flush your Magento cache (see step 2)